# Search multiple ranges and return values to different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Display/Dashboard that lists cars sold within a month broken down by salesman.

I have an input sheet, where the cars are entered weekly.

I'm looking for a way to search the lists of cars sold each week and return the values under the corresponding salesman.

I used IF AND functions however don't believe these are suitable for what I am trying to achieve.

Monthly Display
[image]

[Weekly Input]
[image]

Comment: Try `index/match`?

Comment: Use a Pivot table?

Comment: I think index/match is right however it's more getting the values to be returned to different cells i.e. if cell A1 is the first available "Model" cell but already has a value in it, then the next one would be in cell A5 as that would be the next available "Model" cell if that makes sense?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Filter and lookup formula sound like the way to go.  Pretty impossible to tell without seeing the data though.  Could you add a picture of your data to your question please?  The `Edit` button is just below the tags in your question.

Comment: Thanks Darren have added screenshots.

Comment: Just curious after seeing your two images, I wonder how to know that the data seen in the weekly input image should be put under the name of Dave B in the monthly display image ? Is it coming from S/C column (with value DB) in weekly input image ? So, if (for example) the S/C column value is PR, then put the result under Phil R name in montly display image ? S/C value MH ---> under Mark H. S/C value MD ---> under Michael D ?  Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma that's exactly right the S/C column is the salesman's initials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and if you don't mind to change your "header" in sheet Display ... then first you need to copy your original workbook and test the following sub on the copied workbook.

First, make the header for sheet Display like this :
[image]
Each name is separated by one column. So Mark H will be in column L, and so on.

Step run the sub, please don't hit "play" to run the sub - because the sub is not complete in the select case ---> It only define the oFill for DB and PR.

I don't write a complete sub, but I hope this sample sub may help you to get started.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim arr1: Dim arr2: Dim arr3
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim oFill As Range
Dim x As String: Dim y As String
Dim j As Long: Dim i As Long

'set the worksheet as sh1 and sh2 variable, and set the range of sh1 column A as rg variable
Set sh1 = Sheets("Weekly Input")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Display")
Set rg = sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'this is the loop for 4 week in sheet Weekly Input
'where rg at the first iteration is column A
'2nd iteration is column L, and so on
For j = 1 To 4
    
    'this is the loop to each row of data value in rg (the N/U column)
    For Each cell In rg
        
        'join the name, model, reg and date with comma separated into variable x
        x = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "," & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & "," & _
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "," & cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
            
        'make x value into into array as arr1 variable
        arr1 = Split(x, ",")
        
        'join the prds, fin, px and discount with comma separated into variable y
        y = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value & "," & cell.Offset(0, 6).Value & "," & _
            cell.Offset(0, 7).Value & "," & cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            
        'make y value into array as arr2 variable
        arr2 = Split(y, ",")
        
        'create arr3 variable by joining arr1 and arr2
        ReDim arr3(0 To 1, 0 To UBound(arr1))
            For i = 0 To UBound(arr3, 2)
                arr3(0, i) = arr1(i)
                arr3(1, i) = arr2(i)
            Next

    'check what is the value of the looped row,column S/C
    Select Case UCase(cell.Offset(0, 4).Value)
    
        'if the value is DB
        Case "DB"
            'check, if the looped cell value is u, set the range in sh2 to a blank cell of column B as oFill variable
            'other then "u" (meaning "n"), set the range in sh2 to a blank cell of column D as oFill variable
            If cell.Value = "u" Then Set oFill = sh2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                Else Set oFill = sh2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        'same thing with PR
        'add a similar code for MH and MD pointing to the needed range
        Case "PR"
            If cell.Value = "u" Then Set oFill = sh2.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                Else Set oFill = sh2.Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End Select
        
        'put the arr3 value into oFill
        oFill.Resize(4, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(arr3)

    'looped to the next row of column N/U in sh2
    Next cell

'set the rg for the next iteration of the week
Set rg = rg.Offset(0, 11)

Next j

End Sub
```